# PHP - have a script call itself again to avoid timeout

Tags: php

I have a database with records to process. Number of records will vary. Too many records will cause my script to timeout but 15 records is a good safe number.

If my pseudo code is

```
//script begin
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 0, 15";
runquery($sql);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    //do things then run this sql:
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = {$theCurrentId};";
}
```

, can I achieve something like this at the end of the script:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE status = 0";
runquery($sql);
if (rowcount() > 0) {
    ???? - something to call this script again as a new script
}
```

i.e. can I run this short script again if needed without it being counted in the timeout?

Comment: I think the is a timeout setting for PHP you can change server side. Have you looking into that?

Comment: What would I change the timeout to if the number of records is unknown? - That's my problem.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php `If set to zero, no time limit is imposed` you might want to look at what is hanging it though..

Comment: that is an option but it the last resort as nothing should be allowed to run forever. The hanging is not hanging, it's just workload.

Comment: What is it doing that is taking so long? Maybe you should look at optimizing the workload instead.

Comment: It's doing complicated database stuff on well indexed tables on a server with poor resources. 15 records is fine. Each record takes about 1.5s to process.

Comment: When the script starts the first time save the current time. Then on each cycle check how many seconds remain and if they are too few, add other 15 seconds using set time limit.

Comment: That's a good idea! I think I'll do that if this question cannot be answered.